Можно ли сделать доступ к сайту только через cefsharp?
Есть идея сделать WPF + cefsharp. Суть в чем. Необходимо сделать доступ к сайту по прямой ссылке исключительно через cefsharp. Любые браузеры должны показывать, что нет соединения с сайтом. Есть ли такая возможность? Может быть даже пример?

Вас интересует Mutual SSL Authentication. Это проверка SSL сертификата на стороне сервера для авторизации клиента, по сути, позволяет разрешить доступ только с той машины, на которой был запущен setup.exe

По ссылке руководство, как подписать подобный сертификат и настроить веб-сервер

using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;
using System;

namespace CefSharpMutualSSLAuth
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var settings = new CefSettings();
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-features", "SSLCommonNameMismatchHandling");
            settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ssl-client-certificate", "path_to_your_client_certificate_file.pem");
            settings.IgnoreCertificateErrors = true;

            Cef.Initialize(settings);

            var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
            browser.Load("https://example.com");

            browser.FrameLoadEnd += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Frame.IsMain)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Page loaded successfully!");
                }
            };

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
            Console.ReadKey();

            Cef.Shutdown();
        }
    }
}

